# Syntax for executing a returned function

Tags: javascript

If I return a function from a function as shown below, how do I execute it and set the parameter?

```
var func1 = function(param){
    // do stuff
};

function returnFunction(){
    return func1;
}

returnFunction() // this will return func1 but I want to execute it with certain param.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just execute it like normal:

```
returnFunction()("whatever");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/c32dN/).

To make it a little easier to read:

```
var fn = returnFunction();
fn("whatever");
```

Comment: O.K.  Thanks.  First answer.  This is closed now.

Comment: Should have tried the easiest first..it just looks so weird to to that.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: You cannot close questions. On SO, you _accept_ them.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - Yeah it does look a little weird. If you assign the result of `returnFunction` to a variable, you can then invoke that and it won't look as strange!

Answer (score 2):

Like any other function call:

```
returnFunction()(foobar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to regard functions as some [magical construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744087/javascript-methods-calling-method-without-parentheses/12744640#12744640).

### Calling functions isn't magic

However, a function is simply a value that can be operated on with the `()` operator.

Does `!(x || y)` look weird to you? `!` is very similar to `()` in a way, except that you write it *before* its operand whereas you write `()` *after* the operand. They take a value, operate it, and return a value, that's all there is to it.

Having understood that, `x()()()` *won't* look weird, it's simply *unusual*: `x` is obviously a function, that returns a function, which returns a function, that returns something: the value `(x()()())`

### Applying this new understanding to your example

As you are already aware, `returnFunction()` will return `func1`. Thus, the entire expression `returnFunction()` *yields* the **value** `func1`, and since you can apply the `()` operator to *values*, that's all you need to do:

```
returnFunction()(arg)
```